# Mockito Capture argument of a Constructor in mockConstruction

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following classes:

```
public class Bar {
  
  private final Listener mListener;
  
  public Bar(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
  }

}

public class Foo {
  
  private final int mIntField;
  private final Bar mBarObject;

  public Foo(int intField) {
    mIntField = intField;
    mBarObject = new Bar(new Listener() { ... });
  }

}
```

Currently, I am writing test for `Foo` class and since `Bar` is not injected, I am using `mockConstruction` to force all instance of `Bar` being created after `mockConstruction` call to be mocked. But I want to capture the argument to that constructor (ie Listener). How can I do that?

Comment: Unrelated: follow java naming conventions. That `mMemberField` is frowned upon in java. Albeit ugly, `this.whatever = whatever` is what everybody does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to capture the `Listener` when you write unit-test on `Foo`. Because you are using Mocking framework which isolating indirect dependencies from the test class.

Let's make a simple figure as example. Assuming your actual dependency path is like below:

```
Foo -> Bar -> Listener -> Other -> Other2 -> ...
```

When you test on `Foo`, use mocking framework to make a `MockedBar` and eliminate the dependency path of `Bar`. Then, the dependency path becomes very simple:

```
Foo -> MockedBar
```

As a result, you can test your `Foo` easily.

In order to do that, just refactor your code slightly. First, add a package-private constructor in your `Foo`:

```java
public class Foo {

    private final int mIntField;
    private final Bar mBarObject;

    public Foo(int intField) {
        mIntField = intField;
        mBarObject = new Bar(new Listener() { ... });
    }

    // package-private constructor, for test only.
    Foo(int intField, Bar bar) {
        mIntField = intField;
        mBarObject = bar;
    }
}
```

Second, initialize and inject the `mockedBar` into `Foo` by constructor-injection.

```java
public class FooTest {
    
    private Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        int intField = 123;
        Bar mockedBar = mock(Bar.class);
        when(mockedBar.invokeListener()).thenReturn(something);
        foo = new Foo(intField, mockedBar);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_foo() {
        // test your foo
    } 
}
```

That's all. Now, you don't need to use the magic  function `mockConstruction` anymore.

Comment: So it's impossible to capture the argument of a constructor when using `mockConstruction`? In my case, the listener is invoked internally by the `Bar` class and the invocation is through a private method. I think I have to create a subclass of `Bar` in my unit test.

Comment: I'm not sure if `mockConstruction` could capture the argument. But I think this is unnecessary  in your case. By the way, mocking a constructor is not a good practice. A constructor is just for initialization, without any logic.

Comment: Back to your case, when you mock `Bar`, the `Listener` will not be invoked actually. So it's reasonable to say you don't need to do anything for `Listener`.
One thing you can do is to stub the `public method which invoking the Listener` in `Bar`.

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang It is possible to capture constructor arguments with `mockConstruction`. See my answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
// Map of created Bar(s) and its constructor arguments
// If single object is expected to be created then simple list of objects is enough
final Map<Bar, List<Object>> constructorArgs = new HashMap<>();
try (MockedConstruction<Bar> mockedBarClass = Mockito.mockConstruction(Bar.class,
        (mock, context) -> constructorArgs.put(mock, new ArrayList<>(context.arguments())))) {

    // WHEN
    new Foo(1);

    // THEN
    assertThat(mockedBarClass.constructed()).hasSize(1);
    // Get created object
    Bar createdBar = mockedBarClass.constructed().get(0);
    // Assert constructor arguments
    assertThat(constructorArgs.get(createdBar)).hasSize(1);
    assertThat(constructorArgs.get(createdBar).get(0)).isInstanceOf(Listener.class);
}
```